# I return random Nan from an api using asyncio

Tags: python, api, python-asyncio, finance, aiohttp

I make API calls with asyncio, with large lists I get a lot of Nan. If I split the list into small lists, most of the time the problem is solved, but not always.
When I use the `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` which is commented I get all the results without problems but I sacrifice speed. How can I solve it?

**Note:** I don't understand why `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` works there. Is not `asyncio.gather` the one who executes all tasks one they are created?

```
import pandas as pd
import aiohttp
import requests
import asyncio

async def get_data(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            try:
                data = await resp.json()
                return data[0]['peRatioTTM']
            except:
                pass

async def main(symbols):
    tasks = []
    for symbol in symbols:
        url = f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios-ttm/{symbol}?apikey=APIKEY"
        # await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_data(url)))
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'GOOGL', 'AMZN', 'TSLA', 'VITSX', 'VTSAX', 'FB', 'META', 'NVDA', 'PEP', 'COST', 'AVGO', 'ASML', 'AZN', 'AGTHX', 'CSCO', 'TMUS', 'ADBE', 'CMCSA', 'TXN', 'QCOM', 'AMD', 'INTC', 'HON', 'AMGN', 'INTU', 'QQQ', 'NFLX', 'PYPL', 'ADP', 'SNY', 'JD', 'SBUX', 'VSCIX', 'PDD', 'MDLZ']
    df = pd.DataFrame({'symbols': symbols})
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    res = asyncio.run(main(symbols))
    df['peRatioTTM'] = res
```

Comment: Please never use a bare `except: pass`. You'll never know what the actual exception was, so for all we know, that's the problem here.

Comment: In fact – it's likely you're bumping into a throttle in that API you're using, and that doesn't happen if you slow down things with a sleep. But you'll never know because you swallow all errors.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the API you're using has a rate limit and you're getting an exception when you hit it with a large number of requests simultaneously. If you add a sleep, that won't (necessarily) happen.

Unfortunately, you won't ever know if that happens since you don't call `resp.raise_for_status()` (if the API returns an error), and you swallow all errors that could happen with parsing and reading the JSON with that `try: except: pass`.

You should also share a single `ClientSession` for efficiency. All in all, you might want something like

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def get_ttm(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, symbol: str):
    url = f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios-ttm/{symbol}?apikey=APIKEY"
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        data = await resp.json()
        try:
            return (symbol, data[0]["peRatioTTM"])
        except IndexError:
            return (symbol, None)


async def get_ttms_for_symbols(symbols):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [get_ttm(session, symbol) for symbol in symbols]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    symbol_ttms = asyncio.run(get_ttms_for_symbols([...]))
```

– now you'll have a chance to find out what the exception is and e.g. wait and retry the call if it returns 429 Rate Exceeded or similar.

---

> I don't understand why await asyncio.sleep(0.1) works there. Is not asyncio.gather the one who executes all tasks one they are created?

No, `asyncio.gather` doesn't do work, it just waits for work to have been done.

The `async` coroutine created is perfectly synchronous until the point it first yields control back to the  async loop (using an `await`), in this case likely once the HTTP request has been made. At that point, the server will have counted that request towards your quota, and you get throttled since in its eyes you're sending, say, 50 exactly concurrent requests.

With the sleep, those requests won't be exactly concurrent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, really `try: except: pass` is a big error. Now I see the 429 error but it is not always with the same number of requests, sometimes it is many more and sometimes very few. If I use the sleep with your code, where should I use it and how long?

Comment: You don't want to use `sleep`, you want to make sure you don't make too many concurrent requests, and that you retry when you get a 429.